# Matlab: incorporating known standard deviations for individual data points in boxplot

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a set of about 10 points, which are the result of performing various operations on data originally collected.  Essentially, these 10 points represent fitting parameters of the originally collected data (specifically each corresponds to the same fitting parameter accross 10 different trials).  Thus, I know the standard deviation of each point.

I want to summarize my data in a boxplot (to show the coherence of these different trials), but I don't know how I should go about including my information about the standard deviation of *each point* individually.

Perhaps boxplot is not even the right plot to be using in this case.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `errorbar(X,Y,ERRORS)` would show what you are looking for.  Here is an example:

```
>> x = 0:pi/5:2*pi;
>> x = 0:pi/6:2*pi;
>> y = sin(x);
>> errors = abs(cos(x));
>> errorbar(x,y,errors)
```

This produces the plot:
[image]